# Defining root of HTML in a folder within the site root folder

Tags: html

I want to have a new folder containing a set of new html files. All the images inside it are in the format `src="image.png"` and `image.png` is located in the root folder. But when you put the HTML file in a new folder it can't find the image. You have to have it in the format `src="../root folder/folder/image.png"` to make it work. Which would mean a lot of pasting. I have tried putting `image.png` inside the folder but no change.

Comment: All the answers point to `<base>`, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag carefully

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [**`<base>`** element.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/base) It allows you to specify a URL for all relative URLs in a page.

For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>This is an example for the <base> element</title>
        <base href="http://www.example.com/news/index.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Visit the <a href="archives.html">archives</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The link in the this example would be a link to "http://www.example.com/news/archives.html".

For you, the base URL may be something as simple as `<base href="http://www.yoursite.com/">`. This would make images specificed as `src="image.png"` resolve as `"http://www.yoursite.com/image.png"`

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `base` tag. If you add the tag in your page `<head>` like this:

`<base href="http://yoursite.tld/folder/">`

it should display images and with sources relative to this base path.

Comment: @iambriansreed - point taken. The reference is gone and it wasn't really needed.