# Modify <base> tag dynamically on server side render

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I was looking for how to get a base url for an HTML page, so that relative url requests from the browser use that base.

Here is the answer
[Defining root of HTML in a folder within the site root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371785/defining-root-of-html-in-a-folder-within-the-site-root-folder)

When rendering the HTML from the server - is there a reliable way to add a `<base>` element to the HTML?

**The HTML file is auto-generated, and I do not want to manually add the `<base>` tag to the file, if I can avoid it. It would be nice to add it dynamically somehow, when the page gets rendered.**

So here is the HTML  as it stands:

```
<head>
    <title>Code coverage report for All files</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prettify.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type='text/css'>
        .coverage-summary .sorter {
            background-image: url(sort-arrow-sprite.png);
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

I want to add a base tag when rendering with the server, so it would look like:

```
<head>
    <title>Code coverage report for All files</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="http://localhost:3050/coverage/lcov-report/cdt-now/index.html">  // <<<<
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prettify.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type='text/css'>
        .coverage-summary .sorter {
            background-image: url(sort-arrow-sprite.png);
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

The problem I suppose is that the index.html file is not at the root of my project:

[image]

But the index.html file makes relative path requests as you can see with the `<link>` tags in the `<head>` above.

I am currently rendering the page like this:

```
router.get('/', ac.allow('Admin'), function (req, res, next) {

  let html = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../coverage/lcov-report/cdt-now/index.html');

  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html');
  fs.createReadStream(html).pipe(res);

});
```

Comment: You need some sort of templating. Do you know Jade, EJS...?

Comment: Like I said in the question - the key part is that I don't control the file - it is autogenerated - I don't want to manually modify the file if I can avoid it.

Comment: You don't need to.

Comment: Ok, can you explain more...lol

Comment: I do not control how the file is generated => any changes I make to it, will be overwritten. Therefore, I want to avoid having to add any template code to the file.

Comment: That is what presents the challenge at hand.

Comment: I have a solution, I believe, I will add an answer if it works. It involves using replacestream, and adding the <base> tag  right after <title>

Comment: The best way is how you said, use [replacestream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replacestream), this is a very basic example, but this is the general idea. `var base = '<base href="http://localhost:3050/coverage/lcov-report/cdt-now/index.html">';
fs.createReadStream(html)
    .pipe(replaceStream('<head>', '<head>' + base))
    .pipe(res);`

Comment: @luisenrike thanks, yes you are right.. please add that as an answer and I will upvote/accept

Answer (score 0):

So the way to do this, using my current code which streams the response to the browser, would be:

```
    const replacestream = require('replacestream');

    router.get('/', ac.allow('Admin'), function (req, res, next) {

      let html, val = 'coverage/lcov-report/cdt-now/index.html';

      try {
        html = path.resolve(__dirname + `/../${val}`);
        fs.existsSync(html)
      }
      catch (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html');
      let replacement = `</title><base href="http://localhost:3050/${val}">`;

      fs.createReadStream(html).pipe(replacestream('</title>', replacement)).pipe(res);

    });
```

that is the basic idea.